# Specifying per-table recovery mode

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that is used for log data; the data is only INSERTed, never UPDATEd. The table has no business data whatsoever, and thus it is not a problem if I cannot recover it in case of a disaster.

In addition to inserting, I periodically want to empty this table.

The table has no foreign keys, and only one clustered index on the field which contains the log date/time.

The database recovery mode is currently set to FULL. Is it possible to prevent logging transactions when writing/deleting from this specific table, while still logging changes to other tables?

Comment: What version and edition of SQL Server? Another possibility - if you are on 2014 and Enterprise Edition - is to store this data in an In-Memory table with durability set to schema only. As long as it is accurate that you can lose all of the data in the event of a restart or other service disruption. (This too, though, could be stored in a different database, so that the data never interferes with anything anyway.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Client installations can be running 2012 and non-Enterprise, so I can't set durability.

Answer (score 3):

No, logging and recovery don't work at that level. What I recommend is, instead of trying to make one database serve two different recovery objectives, store this logging information in its own database (or a different, existing database) with alternate recovery objectives.

If that is not an option for some reason, the only thing you can really do to minimize the impact on the log is to:

1. Issue truncate instead of delete - which is still logged, but less so.
2. Instead of allowing for lots of small inserts, queue those up into batches and do what you can to make the eventual insert eligible for [minimally logged transactions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191244(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: I don't think you can get minimally logged INSERTs in Full recovery model @AaronBertrand.

Comment: _queue those up into batches_ - can you elaborate?

Comment: @Zev store the individual inserts in a staging table in another database, then have a background job that does insert real table select top (10000) from staging table.

Comment: @wBob you can switch to bulk-logged without disrupting the log chain. Since I don't know whether that's feasible for this OP, I provided a link instead of 99 disclaimers.

Answer (score 2):

How about a 'normal' table in tempdb?  What I call a semi-permanent table?  As tempdb is in Simple recovery mode, this will reduce the logging overhead in your main database, but the data does become throwaway, eg you will lose it in the event of a server crash or restart.  You can however reference it with a three-part name, eg

```
INSERT INTO tempdb.dbo.myLog ( etc
VALUES ( etc
```

You will have to bear in mind the following:

- you will have to create the table every time the SQL Server starts up, as ...
- the table will be dropped every time SQL Server restarts.  Consider an [auto-start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189915.aspx) proc, or some application/logging logic which checks for the table's existence before logging
- tempdb is a shared resource for the server, consider the impact on other dbs
- you can't backup tempdb
- you will have to size tempdb accordingly, build a job to truncate it every time it gets to 1 million rows for example.

You stand more of chance of getting minimally logged INSERTs with this approach, plus trace flag 610 although the required TABLOCK would be somewhat anti-concurrency.  This is also not worth it/ not applicable if you're logging using INSERT...VALUES.

Worth considering if your log data is as throwaway as you describe.

Comment: I like this idea, but losing this data in a server restart is a bit of a showstopper. The data is throwaway only in the sense that I don't need this data if the database gets corrupted and I have to recover from backups, but I would want to preserve it through server restarts.

Comment: In that case a separate db in Simple recovery mode is a good fit, as per Aaron's suggestion.